# Unity error "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp"

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I'm trying to learn how to code in unity and I followed the instructions on how to download everything I needed. I then created a new projects on Unity Hub and It gave me this error:

```
Unhandled exception. System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp, Version=3.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Format of the executable (.exe) or library (.dll) is invalid.
File name: 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp, Version=3.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
```

I looked up solutions on google for how to fix it but either they didn't work or I didn't understand them.

What do I do?

Comment: do you have VisualStudio installed? / Is your VisualStudio up-to-date? / Could you show which packages you have installed in your VisualStudio?